# Not able to upload image in Magento Backend Admin

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

When I try to upload product image on **Catalog > Manage Products > New Products > Images**, I get an error:

> The directory /var/www/store/media/wysiwyg/ is not writable by server.

Solution I have tried:

- recreate wysiwyg folder
- I try to set permission to 777 for media folder

Also not able to solve the issue.

Does it mean /var and /www folder I need to set the permission to 777 too ?

Comment: try 755 permission & check once , can you able to upload image to this path : `/var/www/store/media/wysiwyg/` through ftp.....

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe Yes. I able upload image to the path via FTP.